# Having trouble with for each loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, each

So I am trying to make this swing GUI that searches a list of books and then displays the book in a JTextArea. Here is my actionPerformed Method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Search Books")){
        String bookName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter books to search"); // prompts user to enter book title
        if (bookName == null){
            sArea.append("Enter a Book");
        }else{
            for (Book b: ban.getListOfBooks()){ //going through list of books to find matching title
                if (bookName.equals(b.getTitle())){ // appends string if it is equal to one of the book names
                    sArea.append(bookName);
                }else{ 
                    sArea.append("Book not found");
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        ...
```

So my problem is for the for each loop. Naturally it will print "Book not found" for every element in the list that is not equal. So if i have ten books, and i enter the name of the first one, it will print that and then "Book not found" nine times. How could i reformat this to only print out one thing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a boolean found flag and then check if the book was found at the end of the loop

```
    }else{
        boolean found = false;
        for (Book b: ban.getListOfBooks()){ //going through list of books to find matching title
            if (bookName.equals(b.getTitle())){ // appends string if it is equal to one of the book names
                sArea.append(bookName);
                found = true;
            }else{ 
            }
        }
        if (!found) sArea.append("Book not found");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to still continue using foreach loop you can extract that part to a function, return the book name when it matches but if any book does not matche return "Not found" instead of appending every iterarion

Like this:

```
public String searchBook(List<Book> books, bookName ){
for (Book b: books)){ //going through list of books to find matching title
    if (bookName.equals(b.getTitle())){ 
        return b.getTitle();
    }
} 

return "Book not found"; }
```

So you just calling this function instead of your foreach loop like this:

```
sArea.append(this.searchBook(ban.getListOfBooks() , bookName))
```

It´s cleaner.

Finally I'm not sure if is correct to use **append** method If you just want to put the result everytime the user search.

Also if you have a List you can use **indexOf** or **contains** methods to know if a element exists in the list, it´s cleaner.

This can help you more : https://www.baeldung.com/find-list-element-java